# WordPress is automatically linking plain text email addresses

Tags: plugin-development, customization, filters, email

I'm using the latest version of WordPress (3.1.1). Is it just me, or is WordPress now automatically linking plain-text email addresses?

I type `jdoe@email.com` as a comment and it shows up as `<a href="mailto:jdoe@gmail.com">jdoe@gmail.com</a>`

I am working on a plugin that filters comment text using the `get_comment_text` filter and then subsequently modifies the presentation of the email address. This plugin worked fine before, but like I said, now WordPress automatically links email addresses.

I figured that WordPress would follow its own rules and do it by means of a filter, so I went ahead and added a priority level to my *own* filter of `9000` figuring that way I can force mine to trigger after WordPress is done sticking its nose in something that's not its business, but this did not work.

I'm wondering if anyone here knows a way around this situation, or at the very least, if someone knowledgeable about the system could point me to the source that is responsible for this automatic linking.

My plugin already has the functionality to work with plain-text emails, but this too is broken because after it modifies the presentation of the plain-text email, WordPress then goes and linkifies it.

**EDIT**: One Trick Poney pointed me to [`make_clickable`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1386) which is responsible for this. It's indeed added as a filter in [`wp-includes/default-filters.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L150), with a priority of `9`. However, I have already tried, like I mentioned above, to set the priority level to `9000` to make my plugin work after WordPress has done its dirty business. This didn't work, is it because I'm getting the original unfiltered content? I figured I would be getting the filtered content (i.e. the content already linked).

So then I went ahead and activated the plain-text filter (which applies to plain-text emails), and applied it a priority of `-9000` so that it gets in before `make_clickable`, but again nothing good came of this because when `make_clickable` did fire, it went ahead and figured it'd be a good idea to linkify the links I create. It 'linkifies' the urls in the `href` attribute of a link, making for very messy output.

So it seems that the best thing to do would be to get in *after* wordpress has done its business, after `make_clickable` has fired, but like I said for some reason even though I apply my filter a priority level of `9000`, compared to `make_clickable` whose priority level is only `9`, nothing seems to happen. I will continue to investigate.

I can understand and imagine that WordPress devs were trying to be more user-friendly, but this seems to have caused some edge-case problems (ex. linkifying href attributes in already-existing links).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 2**: Yep, I just tested my filter with a priority level of 9000, which I would imagine should run *after* WordPress ' `make_clickable` whose priority level is 9. My filter gets the unaltered/unfiltered content. I don't know how or why this is happening. I would have imagined that having a later priority I would get the content as it had so far been altered by higher-priority filters, otherwise situations like these (collisions?) would arise, like this one.

Comment: it's the `make_clickable` filter applied to comment_text. add your filter with `-9000` priority or something like that

Comment: Thanks One Trick Pony I appreciate it! I was just finding out that it's not limited to email addresses, that it also applies to URLs. I'll investigate. If it works out I'll let you know in case you want to make this an answer.

Comment: I've added more information to my post in case you might have any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that wordpress' `make_clickable` filter was attached to the `comment_text` filter hook and not `get_comment_text`, which is what I have been using for a while. I had researched earlier if this may be the case, specifically figuring out what the difference was between the two, and I think I read something about `comment_text` *using* `get_comment_text`, so maybe it was doing something more than once, resulting in the weird output I found.

I solved this by changing my filter to hook onto `comment_text` instead, that way the priority *would* matter (duh), and kept my filter's priority level of 9000. Preliminary tests show everything to be working. This way I don't have to worry about wordpress modifying my output in unpredictable ways, instead I can just bother working with what wordpress vomits out. At least that way I know what I can work with and what I can't work with.

Thanks again to one trick pony for giving me a lead.

Comment: i don't think there's a hook called `get_comment_text` :)